# Add requirement for only dependent app

Tags: django, git, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I am working on my django project on Linux Ubuntu. 
i am not using virualevn. so when i run the command

```
pip freeze > requirement.txt
```

it add the hundreds of lines(apps) to my requirement.txt file. I want only to add those app who will need to run this app only.

is there any way to do it?

Comment: Have you thought about using a virtualenv? :)

Comment: yeh, but i am talking about what if virtualenv is not used then how?

Comment: To me the question sounds a bit like: `I have a nail, a screwdriver and a hammer. How do can I hang up my picture without using the hammer?` If you know how to do it with a virtualenv, why is this not an option for you?

Comment: because i have a project from another developer that is not implement using virutalenv and had lot of app written in requirements.txt file, and i don't know what apps of in these are required or not, i can not do manually to remove one by one and check. that's why i am asking.

Comment: You can go the other way round: install your app in an empty environment, test your package and get rid of all `ImportError`'s by installing the required packages. If your unittests cover your project well, this should not cost much time, even for many dependencies. You should really add the requirements to `install_requires` afterwards and keep `setup.py` up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

There's no automatic way to get only the apps you need. You'll have to construct the requirements file manually. It's not that hard to do though - start by looking at all the imports in all your files an add the apps for those imports. Then run your app in a new virtualenv with only those imports - any time it crashes because of a missing import you know that you need to add another one!

Answer (score 0):

#### Get pip downloaded packages Only

It omits the dependent packages, and can be used to get clean list of downloaded python modules to add in `requirement.txt` file

```
comm -12 <(pip list --format=freeze --not-required) <(pip freeze) > requirements.txt
```

Hope This Helps!

---

> I am not sure whether we should put whatever we received from `pip freeze` or only required packages in `requirement.txt` file

I have Asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526360/should-we-put-all-required-and-their-dependent-packages-on-requirement-txt-or-on)