# Should we put all required and their dependent packages on requirement.txt or only required packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

If I install one package Eg: `pip install bpython` on newly created virtualenv what I receive when I execute

```
pip freeze
```

**Output:**

```
blessings==1.6.1
bpython==0.17
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
curtsies==0.2.11
greenlet==0.4.12
idna==2.6
Pygments==2.2.0
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
wcwidth==0.1.7
```

> **Question:** *Should we need to put all these in `requirement.txt` file* or just `bpython==0.17`

Once i was asked to clean up `requirement.txt` file, so i did updated the code from

```
pip freeze > requirement.txt
```

**TO**

```
comm -12 <(pip list --format=freeze --not-required) <(pip freeze) > requirements.txt
```

And I am still not sure whether I should put all packages what i receive form `pip freeze` or it's okay/better to put only those required packages without dependent packages.

---

Reading the [Document of PIP](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) what I found closest is:

> Requirements files are used to force pip to properly resolve dependencies. As it is now, pip doesn't have true dependency resolution, but instead simply uses the first specification it finds for a project.

I am still as confused as I was earlier, HELP will be appreciated...

Comment: The dependencies will be added automatically by `pip freeze`. Because those are the versions you tested with, they're the versions you want to deploy with. So -- you should have two separate dependency lists: One with the dependencies a human has decided you need (which *shouldn't* contain transitive dependencies); one with the frozen list that reflects what you tested against (which *should* contain transitive dependencies). You should update your dependencies and regenerate the frozen list between releases, but a deployment for a given release should use library versions you ran QA with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I digged myself a lot, and what [@Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) commented above seems most proper way.

> You should have two separate dependency lists: One with the dependencies a human has decided you need (which shouldn't contain transitive dependencies); one with the frozen list that reflects what you tested against (which should contain transitive dependencies)

**However,  Recently with the release of [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv), I think this is the better way to keep track of dependencies.**

It's like npm, much easier to maintain `requirements` and creating `venv`.

> It automatically creates and manages a virtualenv for your projects, as well as adds/removes packages from your Pipfile as you install/uninstall packages. It also generates the ever–important Pipfile.lock, which is used to produce deterministic builds.